# how to use both this.function in Vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

This is mine handleMove function which is basically working like

```
<div class="container" @mousemove="handleMove"></div>
```

I want to pass Multiple function where i have bold in the code the problem is that when i am doing this.moveSelectedNode(diffX,diffY) the other 
this.moveSelectedDecision is not working

The issue is that one Nodes are going in this.moveSelectedDecision and vice versa for the decisions

when i Comment the One this the other this is working Fine

When i comment one this.moveSelectedNode or this.moveSelectedDecision the other one is working all fine

```
  handleMove(e) {
              if (this.action.linking) {
                [this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y] = getMousePosition(this.$el, e);
                [this.draggingLink.mx, this.draggingLink.my] = [this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y];
              }
              if (this.action.dragging) {
                this.mouse.x = e.pageX || e.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft
                this.mouse.y = e.pageY || e.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop
                let diffX = this.mouse.x - this.mouse.lastX;
                let diffY = this.mouse.y - this.mouse.lastY;

                this.mouse.lastX = this.mouse.x;
                this.mouse.lastY = this.mouse.y;
                this.moveSelectedNode(diffX, diffY);
                **this.moveSelectedDecision(diffX,diffY);**
                console.log('I am here');
              }
              if (this.action.scrolling) {
                [this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y] = getMousePosition(this.$el, e);
                let diffX = this.mouse.x - this.mouse.lastX;
                let diffY = this.mouse.y - this.mouse.lastY;

                this.mouse.lastX = this.mouse.x;
                this.mouse.lastY = this.mouse.y;

                this.scene.centerX += diffX;
                this.scene.centerY += diffY;

                // this.hasDragged = true
              }
            },
```

These are mine moveSelectedNode and moveSelectedDecision function which i am passing up in handleMove

```
 moveSelectedNode(dx, dy) {
          let index = this.scene.nodes.findIndex((item) => {
            return item.id === this.action.dragging
          })
          let left = this.scene.nodes[index].x + dx / this.scene.scale;
          let top = this.scene.nodes[index].y + dy / this.scene.scale;
          this.$set(this.scene.nodes, index, Object.assign(this.scene.nodes[index], {
            x: left,
            y: top,
          }));
        },
         moveSelectedDecision(dx, dy) {
          let index = this.scene.decisions.findIndex((item) => {
            return item.id === this.action.dragging
          })
          let left = this.scene.decisions[index].x + dx / this.scene.scale;
          let top = this.scene.decisions[index].y + dy / this.scene.scale;
          this.$set(this.scene.decisions, index, Object.assign(this.scene.decisions[index], {
            x: left,
            y: top,
          }));
        },
```

Comment: Define `not working`. What is the error message?

Comment: The error message is 
Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Comment: Where as if i comment one any of these two Methods the other method is working fine

Comment: You should check whether `let index` gets assigned a NULL value - and immediately exit the function in such a case.

Comment: let me try this